# Recuperar valor da resposta ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, moodle

Tenho um serviço que faz cadastro em um sistema (do código abaixo)

```
  var userstocreate = [
     {
      username: '' + usuario + '',
      password: 'E@d123456',
      firstname: '' + primeiro +'',
      lastname: '' + lastname + '',
      email: '' + email + ''
    }];
    var data = {
      wstoken: token,
      wsfunction: functionname,
      moodlewsrestformat: 'json',
      users: userstocreate
     }
     var response = $.ajax(
     {
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      url: serverurl
      });
```

A resposta desse serviço fica assim...

```
 abort: (a)
always: ()
complete: ()
done: ()
error: ()
fail: ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ()
getResponseHeader: (a)
overrideMimeType: (a)
pipe: ()
progress: ()
promise: (a)
readyState: 4
responseJSON: Array[1]
responseText: "[{"id":29,"username":"arques_nathalia"}]"
setRequestHeader: (a,b)
state: ()
status: 200
statusCode: (a)
statusText: "OK"
success: ()
then: ()
__proto__: Object
```

Como consigo salvar os valores do responseText? esse "[{"id":29,"username":"arques_nathalia"}]"

queria guardar em uma variável pelo menos o ID, é possível?

Comment: Você resgata esses valores no `callback` da função **Ajax**, no `success`, por exemplo.

Comment: Como?, você tem um exemplo? fiz assim success: function (dados) {
                                                                var resultado = dados;
                                                        } mas não consigo usar essa variável resultado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código está comentado.

```
var userstocreate = [
{
   username: '' + usuario + '',
   password: 'E@d123456',
   firstname: '' + primeiro +'',
   lastname: '' + lastname + '',
   email: '' + email + ''
}];

var params = { // Troca o nome dessa variável 'data' para 'params'
   wstoken: token,
   wsfunction: functionname,
   moodlewsrestformat: 'json',
   users: userstocreate
}

var response = $.ajax(
{
   type: 'POST',
   data: params, // Coloque o 'params' aqui
   url: serverurl,
   success: function(data){
       console.log(data); // Aqui você resgata os valores 'data.responseText'
       console.log(data.responseText);
   }
});
```

Comment: Beleza, consegui, mas preciso pegar apenas o ID? como faço? olha como ficou a resposta.  "[Object]
0: Object
id: 38
username: "gallindo_ramires"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]"

Comment: O retorno `json` é como se fosse um `array`. Quando você coloca um `.`(ponto) está determinando a profundidade que quer chegar. Então o `data` é o topo do iceberg, coloque um `.` para ir mais fundo. Nesse caso `data[0].id`. Mas pelo que estou vendo no seu caso está um pouco diferente. Coloque no seu POST como está retornando o `json`, é mais fácil para visualizar.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Melhor explicação impossível, funcionou certinho!

Comment: Opa! Que bom que deu certo. Eu achei que ia ter um possível problema ainda...

Comment: Qual seria? eu to com um simples agora, porque preciso desse valor id pra usar em outra função, e não estou conseguindo...

Comment: Nesse caso terá que colocar o `ID` numa variável, assim: `var id = data[0].id`. Aí você pode usar ele em outra função abaixo da função `ajax`. Porém, terá que adicionar um parâmetro no `ajax`. Pode ser depois de `url: serverurl`. Coloca `,` no final dessa linha e embaixo: `async: false`.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34533/discussion-between-yuri-rodrigues-and-zoom).